# Edit data in IndexedDB by the user

Tags: indexeddb

I wanted to know if the IndexedDB storage is encrypted. If not, would the user have access to edit or delete the data within indexedDB?

Moreover, what is the best way I can protect this data?

Answer (score 0):

Anybody that has access to the account of the user under which the browser session ran can modify the contents of this database and there is not much you could do about it. You could always try to make some artificial protections and encryptions in your code, but since you will be doing it in javascript this user will also have access to the keys and will be able to do anything he wants. Bottom line is that if you care about security, then you definitely shouldn't be storing sensitive data on the client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how does the user can change the data? I tried in the Google chrome Dev-Tools, under resources, and I didn't find an option to edit the data.

Comment: The user can directly edit the corresponding file stored on his disk. He doesn't need to be using any Chrome Dev-Tools, he just needs to know where this file is stored.

Comment: That would very much depend on the operating system that he is using. For example on Windows 10 that would be the c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\ folder. Inside resides the database for the different websites that the user has accessed so far. So it will be trivial for him to just go ahead and do whatever he wants with those files. Obviously another user that doesn't have access to those files won't be able to modify them. But I repeat once again: **NEVER STORE ANYTHING SENSITIVE ON THE CLIENT MACHINE** if you care about its contents.

Comment: I guess it has changed since 2015, because the .ldb files in the Chrome IndexedDB folder are now encrypted. I'm not saying that it's a good idea to put sensitive infos in there, but it is not that trivial to modify the stored data.